# Run non GUI Java program on Server

Tags: java

I'm really experienced when it comes to Java SE, but aside from helping out on a Java EE program running on a application server like *JBoss* i have no experience in running Java server side, only PHP applications.

I want to do the following:
I just want to write a Java program, that listens on a port (if there are incoming connections) which has to run on a server. It's no web application, there's no GUI or any stuff like that. It just needs to be approachable via the net from for example a desktop application.

What do i need to run a simple Java program server side which can accept requests as simple as possible? (Server recommendations for this simple task appreciated).

Comment: Simple stand-alone non-GUI Java program is run exactly like a GUI Java program. The difference is in the program: it will not try to open the GUI.

Comment: I would take a look at [Netty](http://netty.io/) - start there.

Comment: Go through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

Comment: Why is this question 'on hold as unclear'? Looks fine and clear to me...

Comment: Because it is off-topic.

Comment: I can't see any reason to call this "off topic" or unclear. To my eyes it's a valid question, and answers may refer to RMI and other mechanisms for remote invocation. I suggest un-holding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the full stack of webserver, no.  You just need the capability to run a java process.

Check the API for 
ServerSockets http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html
and 
Sockets http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html
which will just allow you to open a specified port and do with it as you please.

Answer (score 1):

it's really simple with an embedded jetty server.  As simple as:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
server.start();
server.join();
```

You just need to implement a handler.

```
public class MyHandler extends AbstractHandler{...
```

and add it

```
server.setHandler(new MyHandler());
```

see http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html

Comment: 'Embedded' Server? Does this mean the Server is embedded in the application? If so, it needs to be one Server approachable from different clients... if im getting something wrong please forgive me i'm a newbie to this kind of stuff in Java ^^.

Comment: This is functionally similar to using Sockets directly, but with a little bit of boilerplate / structure wrapped around it.   If you have the choice, you should use the embedded Jetty.   This means you include and reference the jetty.jar in your classpath, but its still just a plain old java instance.

Comment: Jetty handles all of the sockets/connection pools for you.  You just have to write the code that responds to requests from clients.  It'll be *much* easier than writing the socket and connection pooling code yourself.

Comment: Sounds pretty good, i will check this out!